# Mysql add an index on a json column which contains an array

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-json

I would like to add an index to a json column which contains a json array that looks like this:

```
[{"points": 3.2, "captain": false, "leagueId": 1078}, {"points": 3.2, "captain": false, "leagueId": 1082}, {"points": 3.2, "captain": false, "leagueId": 1084}]
```

The index that I want to create should be on the `leagueId`. Would that be possible?

The MySQL version I'm using is 8.0.26.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) . Personally I am against storing json data type when you deal with complex queries. Normalize the data  and the life would be easier

Comment: Multivalued index indexes the array of values to be indexed whereas your values to be indexed are scalar properties of array elements. So you cannot create this index immediately. And I agree with @ErgestBasha - the data normalization is the best option.

Comment: It would be better to pull `leagueId` out of the JSON and put it in a real table column.  Then index that column.